# How to access non-standard root field in Apollo Client (GraphQL)?

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client

I am using Apollo in my Kotlin Multiplatform Android application. I write requests like this:

```
apolloClient.query(query).execute().onEach{ response ->
    // Here we access data via response.data
}
```

The problem is that the responses to some requests from the server contain non-standard root fields along with the "data" field.
An example of such a response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
       "name": "John",
       "surname": "Smith"
    }
  },
  "other_data": {
    "some_field": "blah blah blah"
  }
}
```

How do I access the `other_data` field in the server response?